# One select on two tables with NULL and not null

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, isnull

I try to get select from two tables and put some data from one to other with ussing WHERE 
(PL/SQL)

I have two tables like those:

table1

```
ID  NAME  COLOR  COMPANY_SHORT_NR
1   a     Green  1
2   b     Red    23
3   c     Blue   null
4   a     Green  null
5   g     Green  1
```

table2

```
ID  SHORT COMP_NAME
1   1     company_name_1 
2   23    comapny_name_2
```

and now I would like to get all data from table 1 with companies names and if its null get info it is null like that

```
1   a     Green  company_name_1 
2   b     Red    comapny_name_2 
3   c     Blue   null
4   a     Green  null
5   g     Green  company_name_1
```

I tried do it like this:

```
select ID
      ,NAME
      ,COLOR
      ,COMPANY_SHORT_NR
from table1
    ,table2
where COMPANY_SHORT_NR = SHORT
```

but this give me only not null values:

```
1   a     Green  company_name_1 
2   b     Red    comapny_name_2 
5   g     Green  company_name_1
```

if i use sth like this:

```
select ID
      ,NAME
      ,COLOR
      ,COMPANY_SHORT_NR
from table1
    ,table2
where COMPANY_SHORT_NR = SHORT or COMPANY_SHORT_NR is null
```

I get thousends of records ... 
If I use only `IS NULL` than it returns me only 2 rows as it should be.

Where I make mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you neen  OUTER JOIN for that

```
select ID
      ,NAME
      ,COLOR
      ,COMPANY_SHORT_NR
from table1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON ( COMPANY_SHORT_NR = SHORT )
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `left join` as below

```
select ID
      ,NAME
      ,COLOR
      ,COMPANY_SHORT_NR
from table1 t1
left join table2 T2 on t1.COMPANY_SHORT_NR = t2.SHORT
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be better to join the tables? like `SELECT ID, NAME, COLOR, COMPANY_SHORT_NR FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.SHORT = t1.COMPANY_SHORT_NR WHERE 1`